# How to print all the shared objects in memory at a particular time?

Tags: c, linux, dll, shared-libraries

In a Linux system, at a particular time there are many processes running and each process is dependent on some dynamic libraries (shared objects). That can be found out by the ldd command. When the process is running, the shared object must be in memory. Likewise there would be many shared objects loaded in the memory of different running processes in the Linux system.

Is there any way to list all those shared objects? Can it be written in C-programming language? Is this feasible to list all the shared objects currently loaded in memory?

Comment: `Is this feasible to list all the shared objects currently loaded in memory?` Traverse all maps files in /proc/<PIDs> and create the list you need.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating skwllsp's comment:

```
    grep '\.so' /proc/*/maps | sort -k6 | uniq -f5
```

From C you can call `system()` or `popen()` with this command string.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically from inside a process (and this is Linux GNU glibc specific) you could use [dl_iterate_phdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html); the example in the man page is doing what you want.